# Timelapse software for Windows

Tags: windows, webcam, timelapse

i'm looking for an application that can make a still photo from a webcam source every few minutes or so. I've been trying Flix, but unfortunately that doesn't make HD images from my HD Logitech webcam. Right now i'm using RTL Video, but it crashes often and only offers a ten day demo version. I'm on Windows XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on XP, you can run Webcam Timershot, free from Microsoft. It is in the Microsoft PowerToys for Windows XP pack, which you could get [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx) or alternatively, a direct link to the Webcam Timershot executable [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/whistler/Install/2/WXP/EN-US/TimershotPowertoySetup.exe).